# Make my font lock config only highlight my keywords when they are upper case

Tags: font-lock

I've got a font lock config that I use to add certain helpful keywords to various modes of my choosing:

```
(defun my-font-lock-keywords (mode)
  (font-lock-add-keywords mode
              '(("\\<\\(FIXME\\|TODO\\|QUESTION\\|NOTE\\)"
                 1 font-lock-warning-face t))))

(mapc #'my-font-lock-keywords
      '(prog-mode text-mode message-mode latex-mode html-mode emacs-lisp-mode
          texinfo-mode sql-mode cc-mode c-mode clojure-mode lisp-mode
          c++-mode))
```

Works great except it matches/highlights lowercase versions of FIXME, TODO, QUESTION, and NOTE too. I only want it to match/highlight upper case versions of those "keywords". How do I need to tweak the regexp to do this?

Comment: Perhaps it has something to do with `case-fold-search`?  See https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Search_002dbased-Fontification.html and https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Font-Lock-Basics.html

Comment: Thanks @lawlist for your response. I didn't know about case-fold-search, or perhaps had forgotten about it. Unfortunately, that didn't make the difference in this situation. I thought that would have been it. Good to know anyway for general case-sensitive searching.

Comment: There is also font-lock-keywords-case-fold-search, but when set to nil, as mine is, it should do case sensitive search.

Comment: My recollection is that the default behavior is case-sensitive, which is why your example looks very similar to the one in the comments of `font-lock.el`.  Perhaps you could try a minimal user-configuration with just the code in your question and see if it works as expected.  If it works as expected with a near zero/empty user-configuration, then it may be time to recursively bisect by commenting stuff out to find out where the deviation from default behavior is occurring.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
(defun my-font-lock-matcher (limit)
  "Search forward for fixme and todos.
LIMIT is the limit of the search."
  (let ((case-fold-search nil))
    (re-search-forward "\\<\\(FIXME\\|TODO\\|QUESTION\\|NOTE\\)"
                       limit 'no-error)))

(defun my-font-lock-keywords (mode)
  (font-lock-add-keywords mode
                          '((my-font-lock-matcher
                             1 font-lock-warning-face t))))

(mapc #'my-font-lock-keywords
      '(prog-mode text-mode message-mode latex-mode html-mode emacs-lisp-mode
                  texinfo-mode sql-mode cc-mode c-mode clojure-mode lisp-mode
                  c++-mode))
```

Comment: To the extent that the original poster is experiencing non-default behavior, this answer should probably be taken in that context -- i.e., it is essentially a "band-aid" to restore default behavior for the duration of the function at issue.